# iPhone 6 can't take pictures in winter

Tags: iphone, temperature

It is impossible to take photos with my iPhone 6 in winter. Temperature can be from 0 Celsius (32 Fahrenheit) to minus 10  Celsius (14 Fahrenheit) i.e. not very low. Phone just turns off without any explanation. I can warm it inside my pocket or coat and take out only for few photos -- it doesn't help.

Once in room it recovers.

Other phones and cameras work well in such conditions.

How to solve this? I suspect they just put some explicit trigger inside.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that they put an explicit trigger inside your device only. My iPhone 6 works fine in the cold.

It is however likely that you could help the problem by replacing the battery in your device. Sudden shutdown is most often caused by battery related problems.

Comment: What is the problem with battery if it continues to work in room?

Comment: You have described the problem in your question - i.e. it fails to deliver the required power when used in cold weather. This is not an uncommon problem with old/worn batteries.